# How to execute servicestack request validation code only

Tags: servicestack

I'm wondering is there a way to flag to servicestack that you only want to execute the fluent validation filter for a request, and not go on to run the real code?

Ideally you could add a property to any request, something like

```
`ExecuteValidationOnly = true`
```

This would be really useful for tests, and for validating forms client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such feature built into ServiceStack, but you can easily add a Request Filter that short-circuits the request based on a QueryString, e.g:

```
public class SkipRequestFeature : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
            if (req.QueryString["SkipRequest"] == "true")
                res.EndRequestWithNoContent();
        });
    }
}
```

And register the plugin just after the ValidationFeature so it's executed after validation, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
Plugins.Add(new SkipRequestFeature());
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I usually unit test my actual `AbstractValidator<T>` class then when I need to test the service I create a mock on the validator and setup validation calls.

So there is a `MyValidatorTests` class and a `MyServiceTests` class.